# woocommerce wordpress running in EC2 AWS loads very slow

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, woocommerce, ram

wodpress Website with woo commerce plugin downs 7 to 8 times in a day because of RAM full. In EC2 AWS , i have 1gb RAM is 1 Gb ram is sufficient to load a woo commerce website ???

Comment: Can you provide more details about the instance and about the config?

Comment: its a micro instance on free tier, Instance id is - i-0030aafed68179592.Please let me know what other info you need?

Comment: Have you tried with a larger instance to test the theory of your instance hardware not being sufficient?